# Compiler error "collect2: Id returned 1 exit status" using classes with QObject (QT 4.7 with Qt Creator)

Tags: c++, qt, virtual, derived, qobject

I've got the following situation in my current project: "collect2: Id returned 1 exit status" returned by the compiler using the following code:

```
#ifndef BASE_02_H
#define BASE_02_H

#include <QtCore>

class Base_02
{

public:
    Base_02();

    virtual void method()=0;
};

#endif // BASE_02_H

#include "base_02.h"
#include <QtCore>

Base_02::Base_02()
{

}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef DERIVED_02_H
#define DERIVED_02_H

#include <QtCore>
#include "base_02.h"

class Derived_02 : public Base_02
{

public:
    Derived_02();
    void method();
};

#endif // DERIVED_02_H

#include "derived_02.h"
#include <QtCore>

Derived_02::Derived_02()
{

}

void Derived_02::method()
{
    qDebug() << "Derived_02::method()";
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

#include <QtCore>

class Base : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Base(Base* p=NULL);

    virtual void method()=0;
};

#endif // BASE_H

#include "base.h"
#include <QtCore>

Base::Base(Base* p)
{

}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef DERIVED_H
#define DERIVED_H

#include <QtCore>
#include "base.h"

class Derived : public Base
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Derived(Derived* p=NULL);
    void method();
};

#endif // DERIVED_H

#include "derived.h"
#include "derived_02.h"
#include <QtCore>

Derived::Derived(Derived* p)
{

}

void Derived::method()
{
    Derived_02 d;
    d.method();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore>
#include "base.h"
#include "derived.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);



    Derived* derived = new Derived();



    return a.exec();
}
```

The compiler says the following:

> ...
>   mingw32-make: Entering directory `C:/Entwicklung SVN/debug test/dataSenderReceiverExample' 
>   C:/Qt/2010.04/mingw/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug 
>   mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory`C:/Entwicklung SVN/debug test/dataSenderReceiverExample' 
>   g++ -c -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"......\Qt\2010.04\qt\include\QtCore" -I"......\Qt\2010.04\qt\include" -I"..\dataSenderReceiver" -I"......\Qt\2010.04\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"......\Qt\2010.04\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o debug\main.o main.cpp 
>   main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)': 
>   main.cpp:14: warning: unused variable 'derived' 
>   g++ -enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable-auto-import -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -Wl -o debug\dataSenderReceiverExample.exe debug/main.o -L"c:\Qt\2010.04\qt\lib" -L../dataSenderReceiver/debug -ldataSenderReceiver -lQtCored4 
>   mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Entwicklung SVN/debug test/dataSenderReceiverExample' 
>   mingw32-make: Leaving directory`C:/Entwicklung SVN/debug test/dataSenderReceiverExample' 
>   ../dataSenderReceiver/debug/libdataSenderReceiver.a(derived.o):C:\Entwicklung SVN\debug test\dataSenderReceiver/derived.cpp:14: undefined reference to `Derived_02::Derived_02()' 
>   ../dataSenderReceiver/debug/libdataSenderReceiver.a(derived.o):C:\Entwicklung SVN\debug test\dataSenderReceiver/derived.cpp:15: undefined reference to`Derived_02::method()' 
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 
>   mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug\dataSenderReceiverExample.exe] Error 1 
>   mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2 
>   The Prozess "C:/Qt/2010.04/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe" wurde mit dem Rückgabewert %2 beendet.
>   Fehler beim Erstellen des Projekts dataSenderReceiverExample (Ziel: Desktop)
>   Beim Ausführen des Build-Schritts 'Make'

Please help!

Comment: Looks like derived.cpp and derived_02.cpp don't get comoiled. Are you using QtCreator or do you run this on the commandline? What's your makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include "base_02.h"
#include <QtCore>
```

has to be:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include "base_02.h"
```

Then it compiles!

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem in the following situation:

---

Say

A is an executable (f.i. console) project and
B and C are library (f.i. static lib) projects and
A uses B and B uses C.

Then

A has to know B library and C library via .pro file and
B has to know C library via .pro file.

---

Say

in the A .pro file library C is denoted before library B:

```
LIBS *= -L"../C/debug"
LIBS *= -lC
INCLUDEPATH *= "../C"

LIBS *= -L"../B/debug"
LIBS *= -lB
INCLUDEPATH *= "../B"
```

Then

exactly the error described above accures.

---

Solution:

Name library B before library C in the A .pro file:

```
LIBS *= -L"../B/debug"
LIBS *= -lB
INCLUDEPATH *= "../B"

LIBS *= -L"../C/debug"
LIBS *= -lC
INCLUDEPATH *= "../C"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I got same problem here...??
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class employee{
    protected:
        int id; 
        string name;
        int day;
        int salary;
    public:
        virtual void calsalary()=0;
};
class facultyemp:public employee{
    public:
        static int k;
        facultyemp(){
            k++;
            id=k;
        }
        void setname(){
            cout<<"Enter name:";
            cin>>name;
        }
        void setday(){
            cout<<"Enter worked days:";
            cin>>day;
        }
        void setsalary(){
            cout<<"Enter salary pr day:";
            cin>>salary;
        }
        void getname(){
            cout<<"Name: "<<name;
        }
        void getid(){
            cout<<"\nID: "<<id;
        }
        void calsalary(){
            cout<<"The net salary: ";
            cout<<day*salary;
        }

};
static int k=0;
int main(){
    employee *e;
    facultyemp f;
    e=&f;
    f.setname();
    f.setday();
    f.setsalary();
    f.getname();
    f.getid();
    e->calsalary();

}
```

Comment: Explain why this is an answer to the question.